# Displaying a PHP result

Tags: php

I am trying to learn php together with MYSQL. I have built the database on on the from end I have written the code below to bring in the website title from the database which works. However, I have two questions.

1. How would I get the result to display in `<h1>` tags?
2. Is this the cleanest way of pulling this value through?

Any help or advise greatly appreciated

```
<?php
include 'connection.php';

$sql = "SELECT VariableValue FROM VariableValues WHERE VariableID = '1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($header = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo $header["VariableValue"].  "<br>";
}

?>
```

Comment: If you only have one row, why are you looping through rows? Remove the `while()` part, just `$header = $result->fetch_assoc()` will do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can echo all types of tags in PHP echo
for example:

```
echo '<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-8 col-sm-offset-2">
          <div id="success_alert" align="center" class="alert alert-success">
              <strong>Log in to download this chapter.</strong>
          </div>
      </div>';
```

I have echoed different types of bootstrap tags in echo. Similarly you can also echo all types of tags you want.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question.

Answer (score 1):

**To get a single row from db, you could use this:**

```
$header_title = implode(mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT VariableValue FROM VariableValues WHERE id = 1 LIMIT 1")));
```

**Put a php variable between a html tag :**

```
<tag><?php echo $var; ?></tag>
```

Eg :

```
<title><?php echo $header_title; ?></title>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using my code above it pulls through the value, changing to yours it doesn't pull through anything. Any idea what I am doing wrong?
<?php

$header_title = implode(mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query("SELECT VariableValue FROM VariableValues WHERE VariableID = 1 LIMIT 1")));
?>
<h1><?php echo $header_title; ?></h1>

Comment: Try removing the `LIMIT 1`.

Comment: Just tried removing and still doesnt want to pull it through. Its weird as the original pulls through fine, any other ideas?

Comment: Sorry my bad, add `$conn` before the query with the mysqli_query. Like this : `mysqli_query($conn,<sql_query>)`

Comment: @Trotterwatch Select the correct answer, you have ticked a wrong answer.

Answer (score 0):

To displays it in tags, use `<h1><?php echo $var; ?></h1>` for example.